# Assuming that A rolls first, find the probability that the final roll is made by A

Tags: probability

I've a question about this probability's problem:

> A and B alternate rolling a pair of dice, stopping either when A rolls the sum 9 or when B rolls the sum 6. Assuming that A rolls first, find the probability that the final roll is made by A.

Now, I know how to solve this problem by considering every possible turn for the A's final roll. Summing all the possibilities will lead to an infinite geometric series, hence, the answer.

However, there's an easier way to solve this problem:

> Let $P_A$ be the probability that A wins when A rolls first, and let $P_B$ be the probability that B wins when B rolls first. Using that the sum of the dice is 9 with probability $\frac{1}{9}$, we obtain upon conditioning on whether A rolls a 9 that
> $P_A = \frac{1}{9}+\frac{8}{9}(1-P_B)$
> Similarly,
> $P_B=\frac{5}{36}+\frac{31}{36}(1-P_A)$
> Solving these equations gives that $P_A=\frac{9}{19}$ (and that $P_B=\frac{45}{76}$.)

This solution is by the author Sheldon M. Ross of the A First Course in Probability textbook.

How he got this solution? Especially, the part $(1-P_B)$. A detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solution considers only the first toss.  You might find it easier to consider the first two tosses.  In that case, three things are possible:  $A$ wins, $B$ wins, the game restarts.  Thus $$P_A=\frac 19\times 1+\frac 89\times \frac 5{36}\times 0 +\frac 89\times \frac {31}{36}\times P_A$$

from which you can easily compute $P_A$.

To do it the book's way, consider only the first toss.  Either $A$ wins  (prob. $\frac 19$) or not (prob. $\frac 89$).  In the latter case we are in the game in which $B$ is starting.  By definition, the probability that $B$ wins in that game is $P_B$ so the probability that $A$ wins in that game is $1-P_B$.  But of course the probability that $A$ wins is the $\frac 19$ times the probability that $A$ wins on the first toss plus $\frac 89$ times the probability that $A$ wins given that $A$ eventually wins given that it is now $B's$ turn.   That's what the given formula says.

Worth working it out in both ways, just for practice.

Comment: Alright. I see that $Pr(P_A|$A doesn't roll a sum of 9$)=1-P_B$. But, why $P_B$ is defined as the event that B wins when **B rolls first** and not that B wins when **B rolls second**? If it's something related to the recursion, I don't see the game restart at that point.

Comment: The author is free to define $P_B$ however they like.  It makes sense to define it their way since, given that $A$ has just thrown a non-nine, then $B$ is now starting the game.   I repeat, though, that I think the way I sketched is clearer.  Let each player toss once.  Either the winner is determined or the game restarts.  But my way is not the same as Ross' way.